# How do I get only the image URL from the_post_thumbnail()?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want to know how to get just the image URL from `the_post_thumbnail()`. The default output of `the_post_thumbnail()` is:

```
<img width="800" height="533" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/book06.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="book06" title="book06" />
```

Here I want grab the `src` only. How do I filter `the_post_thumbnail()` to get only `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/book06.jpg`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Thumbnail Path rather than Image Tag](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4745/getting-thumbnail-path-rather-than-image-tag)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You might also try:

If you only have one size thumbnail:

```
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
```

Or...if you have multiple sizes:

```
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "size" );
```

Note that wp_get_attachment_image_src() returns an array: url, width, height, is_intermediate.

So if you just want only the image url:

```
echo $thumbnail[0];
```

Resources:

- http://wpcanyon.com/tipsandtricks/get-the-src-attribute-from-wordpress-post-thumbnail/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

Comment: A little hint: if you are using wp_get_attachment_image_src() function with size and want to get exact thumbnail size: use thumbnail name given in definition (function add_image_size()). If you use array with dimensions WP will use first image size that have proper width or height. So you may get wrong image. Example: instead of 156x98 you might have got 120x98 if you have 2 images defined: 156x98 & 120x98 (height is the same). I fell for it once ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since WordPress 4.4, there's an efficient core function that can handle this in a cleaner way than the answers here.

You can use [`the_post_thumbnail_url( $size )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url) which will print the URL of the post thumbnail.

Alternatively if you want to return the URL instead of immediately output it, you can use [`$url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, $size )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/)

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick:

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src('subgall-thumb'); ?>
```

Make sure you use the correct name for the thumbnail that you are calling.

Comment: I don't know if this has changed since 2012, but in 2017 the first parameter of `wp_get_attachment_image_src` must be the attachement id number, not the size.

Answer (score 1):

Ok got it using [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

```
$dom = simplexml_load_string(get_the_post_thumbnail());
$src = $dom->attributes()->src;
    echo $src;
```

Another method are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Please Use the below code**

```
<?php get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>
```

**If It's not enough to achieve your goal then try below code**

```
<?php $postimages = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'large' );

// Check for images if ( $postimages ) {

    // Get featured image   $postimage = $postimages[0];

} else {} while (have_posts() && $i < 8) : the_post(); echo esc_url( $postimage ); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

#### For a quick & dirty solution, slap this in the `functions.php` file of your theme

```
FUNCTION GET_STRING_BETWEEN($STRING, $START, $END){
    $STRING = " ".$STRING;
    $INI = STRPOS($STRING, $START);
    IF ($INI == 0) RETURN "";
    $INI += STRLEN($START);
    $LEN = STRPOS($STRING, $END, $INI) - $INI;
    RETURN SUBSTR($STRING, $INI, $LEN);
}
```

#### Used within the loop, this will give you what you're looking for

This will return something like `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/toy-story-two-was-ok.jpg`

```
$THE_FEATURED_IMAGE = GET_STRING_BETWEEN(get_the_post_thumbnail(NULL,'post-large'), 'src="', '" class="');
```

"Within the loop" means look for something like `while ( have_posts() ): the_post();`.

You can also sub out `post-large` with any of these predefined image sizes:

- `post-thumbnail`
- `post-medium`
- `post-full`

Comment: that's bad. why do you use all caps for your codes?