# Post thumbnails Retrieve Url

Tags: theme-development

Hi I am trying to instegrate a slider into my wordpress theme.This is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
                            $slider_query = new WP_Query(array(
                                        'posts_per_page'=>'5'
                            ));

                            if($slider_query->have_posts()):
                                while($slider_query->have_posts()):
                                    $slider_query->the_post();
                                        if(function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') && has_post_thumbnail()){
                                            the_post_thumbnail();
                                        }
                                 endwhile;
                            endif;
?>
```

While this does work and retrieves the image I need to be able to retribe the url because I have to set different title attributes that are stored for the caption.

I have also tryed to get the URL using

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(the_post_thumbnail());
```

But for som reason the query returns 10 links img's and I set it to 5 only.Wierd thing is that the even images have no source.

Anyone know of a way to retrieve the thumbnail url other then this?
If not then why do I get 10 images in the query?

Comment: Dupe of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/how-do-i-get-image-url-only-on-the-post-thumbnail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `showposts` instead of `posts_per_page`.

Comment: A code sample and – more important – an **explanation** could turn this fragment into an answer. ;)